# how to paint images on clicking button in frame?

Tags: java, button, paint

I've made two buttons in frame .I want to know how to display different images on clicking different buttons?
is there another way out or i have to make panel?I am at beginner stage

```
package prac;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class b extends Frame implements ActionListener{
String msg;
Button one,two;

b()
{   setSize(1000,500);
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    one=new Button("1");
    two=new Button("2");

    add(one);
    add(two);

    one.addActionListener(this);
    two.addActionListener(this);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    msg=e.getActionCommand();
    if(msg.equals("1"))
    {
        msg="Pressed 1";
    }
    else
        msg="pressed 2";
repaint();      
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawString(msg,100,300);
}
public static void main(String s[])
{
    new b();
}
}
```

Comment: Is the answer helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JLabel` and change the icon when button is clicked.

Some points:

- call `setVisible(true)` in the end after adding all the component.
- use `JFrame#pack()` method that automatically fit the components in the `JFrame` based on component's preferred dimension instead of calling `JFrame#setSize()` method.

sample code:

```
final JLabel jlabel = new JLabel();
add(jlabel);

final Image image1 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/1.png"));
final Image image2 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/2.png"));

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton jbutton1 = new JButton("Show first image");
jbutton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        jlabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image1));
    }
});

JButton jbutton2 = new JButton("Show second image");
jbutton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        jlabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image2));
    }
});

panel.add(jbutton1);
panel.add(jbutton2);
add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```