# image not overlapping button

Tags: java, image, button

i want to overlap image on button(when it is clicked)....but on clicking it is not overlapping....please guide me where i am wrong....is it not possible to do so???
i am using frame to add buttons....

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class d extends Frame implements ActionListener {
    Image img, i1, i2;
    int x, y;
    String msg;
    Button one, two;

    d() {

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        setSize(1000, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        one = new Button("1");
        two = new Button("2");
        add(one);
        add(two);
        one.addActionListener(this);
        two.addActionListener(this);

        one.setBounds(200, 100, 100, 100);
        two.setBounds(300, 100, 100, 100);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        msg = e.getActionCommand();
        if (msg.equals("1")) {
            msg = "Pressed 1";
            img = i1;
            x = 200;
            y = 100;
        } else {
            msg = "Pressed 2";
            img = i2;
            x = 300;
            y = 100;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        i1 = tool.getImage("F:/Memories/rawk garden/a.jpg");
        i2 = tool.getImage("F:/Memories/rawk garden/b.jpg");
        g.drawImage(img, x, y, 100, 100, this);
        g.drawString(msg, 100, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        new d();
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want to do? do you want an image button or want to paint a image when button is clicked and hide the button?

Comment: i want to paint a image when button is clicked and hide the button...plz help....!!! @Braj

Comment: you want to hide both the button or just the clicked one.

Comment: just the clicked one...other one should remain button only and replaced by image when clicked @Braj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already shared you code for this in your [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716597/how-to-paint-images-on-clicking-button-in-frame?answertab=votes#tab-top) where I suggested you some points with the sample code to achieve it using `JLabel`.

[Read more points...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340271/why-doesnt-the-ball-show-up-in-the-frame-if-i-add-the-ball-after-the-for-loop?answertab=votes#tab-top)

---

Don't use `null` layout. There are lots of Layout Managers choose any one that suits as per your application design.

[How to Use Various Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)

From comments below:

> actually I am making **minesweeper** type game...i want button to change into image and once one button is converted to image...that image remains there.

Use `JButton#setIcon()` method to set the icon of the button.

Here is the sample code where

- I have created a 9x9 grid that contains buttons.
- Each cell has a random boolean flag whether it has mine or not.
- When button is clicked I am setting its icon if it has mine.
- Simply set the text empty and make it disabled to stop further clicks on already clicked button.

sample code:

```
final Image mine = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/mine.png"));
final boolean[][] showMine = new boolean[9][9];
Random random = new Random();
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9, 9));
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {

        showMine[i][j] = random.nextBoolean();

        final int x = i;
        final int y = j;
        final JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setText(String.valueOf(i * 9 + j));
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button.setEnabled(false);
                button.setText("");
                if (showMine[x][y]) {
                    button.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(mine));
                }
            }
        });

        panel.add(button);
    }
}
add(panel);
```

snapshot:

[image]

Comment: iam unable to run this code...line second"add(jlabel)" is showing error that "jlabel cannot be resolved to type"...please guide..!!

Comment: It's not a complete code. just paste the code in your class constructor.

Comment: thanks...it's working....but image is not overlapping button...i want image to overlap button...that is,like i have button of size 100-height 100-width....i want a 100-height and 100-width image cover that button on clicking that button

Comment: actually iam making minesweeper type game...i want button to change into image and once one button is converted to image...that image remains there

Comment: Sounds Good. You're welcome. If the problem is solved then please close the thread by accepting the post by ticking green right mark.

Answer (score 0):

Setting an image on a button can be done as follows:

```
Button myButton = new Button(new ImageIcon("image_path"));
```